# Newbie How to install on Compaq EVO XP laptop using usb

Tags: 12.04

I am downloading Ubuntu to use with my Compaq XP laptop, which currently has XP (3) installed.  Should I partition, or just format the hard drive? I do not intend to return this machine to XP. What can I download with XP to create a bootable usb drive, that can be read by the machine once the computer is formatted?

TY GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instructions here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

You can let Ubuntu installer to do the partitioning. It's really easy.